# Question about '...only as a sorcery.' abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This is a (hopefully) quick question, there are several abilities that can be cast 'only as a sorcery', like a planeswalkers loyalty, or the Outlast ability.

Can these be used multiple times in one turn, if not forbidden (i.e. because the card is tapped)?

Comment: duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/hypersonic-dragon-instant-scavenge and http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15183/what-are-the-limitations-on-using-a-planeswalkers-loyalty-abilities?

Comment: I feel like you would only ask this question if you were under the impression that you can only cast one sorcery a turn. But in fact, there is no such limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability text "Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery" only affects **when** you can activate it, not how many times or anything else. Rule [602.5d](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Activated_ability) says

> Activated abilities that read "Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery" mean the player must follow the **timing rules for casting a sorcery spell**, though the ability isn't actually a sorcery. The player doesn't actually need to have a sorcery card that he or she could cast.

The Outlast ability can be confusing because the reminder text is worded "Activate only as a sorcery," but that is just because the wording is shortened to fit in reminder text. The full wording of [the Outlast rule](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Outlast) is

> Outlast is an activated ability. "Outlast [cost]" means “[Cost], {T}: Put a +1/+1 counter on this creature. **Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery**."

Planeswalkers have [their own rule](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Planeswalker) that specifically forbids activating their abilities more than once per turn:

> **306.5d** Each planeswalker has a number of loyalty abilities, which are activated abilities with loyalty symbols in their costs. **Loyalty abilities follow special rules**: A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent he or she controls any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of his or her turn, but **only if none of that permanent’s loyalty abilities have been activated that turn**. See rule 606, "Loyalty Abilities."

Answer (score 1):

Activated abilities can be activated as many times as you like as long as you can pay the cost. However, Planeswalkers' abilities have their own rules that say you can only activate them once.